# AWS SQS does not trigger lambda aliases

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, queue, alias, amazon-sqs

I have a lambda function with 2 aliases.

```
Dev - Points to the $LATEST version
Test - Points to a specific version.
```

I have setup my SQS queue to trigger both aliases when it receives a message in the queue. However, it only seems to trigger one of them (The one that got registered the latest) and not both. Has anyone else come across this issue?

```
arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXXXXX:function:Amoel:Dev
arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXXXXX:function:Amoel:Test
```

Comment: How have you configured two Lambda functions to trigger on the queue?

Answer (score 3):

A message on the queue would be consumed only once, by whichever Lambda function grabs it.

If you wish to send the same message to multiple AWS Lambda functions, **combine it with Amazon SNS**:

```
SQS queue -> SNS topic -> 2 x Lambda function subscriptions
```

Be sure to activate **Raw Message Delivery** on the Amazon SNS topic to preserve the original format of the message from Amazon SQS.